# How does ASP.NET know whether a request is AJAX or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm writing an MVC application and I was stunned to know that I could do a Request.isAJAXRequest() in my controller and return a JSONResult if it was AJAX, or return a regular HTML Razor View if it wasn't.

This is incredibly useful, but I'm wondering how this actually works underneath. Is there something in the header that designates it as AJAX?

Here is the request header of an AJAX POST that I pulled from IE Developer tools.
[image]

Comment: It's right there: `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest`

Comment: What other "kinds" of "X-Requested-With" requests are there?

Comment: The `X-` prefix has been reserved for non-standard headers (as in: you can make up your own), but some of them became standard since then and it's no longer the case. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Common_non-standard_request_headers

Comment: @matrixugly: `X-` headers are selfdefined headers, you can put anything you want in them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the header called `X-Requested-With` tells the server that `XMLHttpRequest` was used to make the request (i.e. Ajax).

Answer (score 2):

it's **X-Requested-With** header in the **request** headers.

and because the header can be **removed** or **changed** it's not a complete, guaranteed solution to detect **ajax** calls.

**update:**

in your situation ( return proper format to client ), another way could be to check **Accept** header. it could be json , xml , html or [other things](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRQ_Headers.html#z3). based on that you can decide what to return back.

Comment: What would the "complete, error-proof" solution be?

Comment: I think I should use guaranteed instead of error-proof. anyway I can't say there is any at all. what I said is a general problem. request headers can be manipulated easily, so there is no guarantee that what your method receives is an ajax call.